# Dying during shooting

Tags: production

If an actor dies in front of the camera while they're shooting the movie, can they legally keep the shot (assuming the relatives don't have a problem with that)?

If they can, were there ever a movie which did this?

Comment: Maybe for the first part: http://law.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Are you specifically asking about actors? It's happened a number of times with stuntmen, with the footage ending up in the final movie. e.g. XXX - http://www.toptenz.net/10-movie-stuntmen-died-job.php

Comment: @Tom77 Yes, I'm actually interested in stuntmans too. You could post that as an answer

Comment: In most western countries at least (where I have most familiarity) there would be no legal reason for not 'keeping the shot'.  It might be considered 'bad taste' to deliberately use a death of an actor in a movie.  Though not of actors, there are a ton of examples of real death's captured on video that are shown without the consent of families on News programs and websites.

Comment: The Crow developed the urban tale that the fatal shooting of Brandon Lee was used on the final movie, but that is not true. The footage of his death was destroyed after being reviewed as evidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no law that prevents it from being used, even if the family doesn't consent. The film is property of the movie company.

That said, a look at [List of entertainers who died during a performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_entertainers_who_died_during_a_performance) seems to indicate it has never happened on movies. Closet thing to it is live interviews.